# Is infinite product of Z a group?

Tags: group-theory, infinite-product, infinite-groups

Having the usual coordinate-wise addition, does infinite product of $\mathbb{Z}$ forms a group?

$a,b\in \prod ^\infty \mathbb{Z}$

$a=(a_1,a_2,...)$

$b=(b_1,b_2,...)$

$a\circ b=(a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2,...)$

Then, is $(\prod ^\infty \mathbb{Z},\circ)$ a group?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: This group is the same as the set of function $\mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$ with pointwise addition.

Answer (score -1):

As Pedro said, yes.  It would be a good exercise to try and prove yourself that the axioms hold.

Comment: The question asks only if it is, not how to prove it.  It is absolutely false to say this does not answer the question.

Comment: @k170: I don't think it should just be a comment, I think it should be an answer and so I posted it as an answer.  This is the extent of information that the people here are likely to supply in answer to this question and as you reluctantly admit it is a correct answer to the question that was asked.  That makes it an answer, not just a comment.  As a community wiki answer you are free to improve it if you'd like to.  That would be the constructive way for you to handle your problems.

Comment: @k170: It is a low quality question, so of course it is a low quality answer.  Why would like it to have no answer at all?